# Does backbone-deep-model replace backbone.js collections?

Tags: backbone.js

I'm currently learning Backbone.js and came across [backbone-deep-model](https://github.com/kahwee/backbone-deep-model). Does this replace the regular Backbone Collection since you can create lists in backbone-deep-model?

Comment: Not neccessarly, Backbone-Deep-Models comes to give us to use nested model properties more smoothly and efficiently.

Comment: No... Going *deep* is not really a *collection*. A collection is a collection of items at same level.